# Set up cookie for page visit

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I want to set up 2 cookies. One that shows how many times a user entered the page, and the other shows the date and the time of last visit.
The code works fine, but I need my cookies set up once a day, not every time I visit the page. What I need is to set the `if($_COOKIE['lastTime'] != date('d-M-Y'))` statement, but I need to compare only the 'd-M-Y' part of `$_COOKIE['lastTime']`. Also, I can't set `$lastTime = date('d-M-Y')` (without h-i-m-s), because I need to show the date AND the time of last visit.
Please, help.

```
$counter = 0;
if(isset($_COOKIE['counter'])){
    $counter = $_COOKIE['counter'];
}
$counter++;

$lastTime = '';
if(isset($_COOKIE['lastTime'])){
    $lastTime = $_COOKIE['lastTime'];
}
$lastTime = date('d-M-Y H-i-m-s');

if($_COOKIE['lastTime'] != date('d-M-Y')){
    setcookie('counter', $counter);
    setcookie('lastTime', $lastTime);
}


print_r('This is your ' . $_COOKIE['counter'] . ' visit');
echo '<br>';
print_r('Last visit was: ' . $_COOKIE['lastTime']);
```

Comment: So comparing the last `'d-M-Y H-i-m-s'` datetime string with just `'d-M-Y'` doesn't match for some reason?

Comment: I know that the problem is within the comparing, but I don't know how to set $_COOKIE['lastTime'] inside the if statement to show 'd-M-Y' only.

Comment: please echoing first echo $_COOKIE['lastTime'] ."#". date('d-M-Y'); We will see that values

Answer (score 1):

I left commented lines in the scope, so you can see what can be optimised to get *brevity* to your code. Those commented lines are not needed at all.

```
print_r('Previous visit was: ' . isset($_COOKIE['lastTime'] ? date("Y-m-d", $_COOKIE['lastTime']) : 'not set yet')); 

$counter = 0;
if(isset($_COOKIE['counter'])){
    $counter = $_COOKIE['counter'];
}
$counter++;

$lastDay = '';
if(isset($_COOKIE['lastTime']) {
    $lastDay = date("Y-m-d", $_COOKIE['lastTime']);
}
$currentDay = date("Y-m-d");

if(!$lastDay || $lastDay < $currentDay) {
    setcookie('counter', $counter);
    setcookie('lastTime', strtotime($currentDay));
}

print_r('This is your ' . $_COOKIE['counter'] . ' visit');
echo '<br>';

// here you print a readable datetime format from your stored date
print_r('Last stored visit date was: ' . date("Y-m-d", $_COOKIE['lastTime']));
```

Comment: It still updates the counter after each page refresh. And I need to update the counter once a day.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$lastTime = date('d-M-Y');
```

and not this:

```
$lastTime = date('d-M-Y H-i-m-s');
```

Comment: I know that $lastTime = date('d-M-Y') works, but I need to show the last visit date AND time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$lastTime = '';
if(isset($_COOKIE['lastTime'])){
       $lastTime = $_COOKIE['lastTime'];
}
$lastTime = date('d-M-Y H-i-m-s'); <-- you're overwriting any retrieved value here
```

Check if you got a value first so you don't overwrite it, and then extract just the date part:

```
$lastTime = '';
if(isset($_COOKIE['lastTime'])){
    $lastTime = $_COOKIE['lastTime'];
}
if(strlen($lastTime) == 0)
    $lastTime = date('d-M-Y H-i-m-s');

$parts = explode(" ", $lastTime);
$lastDay = $parts[0];

if($lastDay != date('d-M-Y')){...
```